# Embed private Tableau dashboards on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tableau-api

I'm trying to incorporate one of my Tableau dashboards into a Wordpress page. The dashboard is published on our private servers, hence only visible for certain users, who first have to login to view it.

Is there an easy way/plugin to incorporate these dashboards into a Wordpress page, incorporating the login credentials within the HTML code?

I tried stuff like iframe, but for obvious reasons, this only works for public dashboards.

Links or tips would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look into using what Tableau calls "Trusted Authentication." There are a few methods they give you to accomplish this, so it will depend mostly on your configuration.

The general idea is that you authenticate once with Tableau server and it returns a ticket that you can use (usually for the duration of the session). With that, you can essentially imitate any user, so if you have user-specific data it will work as though they logged in.

You will need administrator access to your Tableau server to configure this.

Here are the docs for Trusted Authentication:

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm